# What concept shall i used to move a sprite object (COCOS2d)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Im currently making a cocos2d-iphone game and I have a question on what action or any concept in cocos2d to move my sprite obj. given an array of points(x,y coordinates).
....
For example:

```
for (int nCtr = 0; nCtr < [m_ArrayPosition count]; nCtr++) {
        dictionary = [m_ArrayPosition objectAtIndex:nCtr];
 arrayPoints = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Points"];
 strTempX = [arrayPoints objectAtIndex:0];
 strTempY = [arrayPoints objectAtIndex:1];
        id move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.1 position:ccp([strTempX floatValue],[strTempY floatValue])];
 [m_seeker runAction:move];
}
```

....
What happened here is that the runAction will only execute the first loop or first (x,y) and then the loop skips the rest.

My array of points is from the users touch point point in the device so this is not fixed.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should created a [CCSequence](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_sequence.html) to run many actions one after another, and then tell the target to runAction with that sequence.